# Unable to start neo4j with systemctl: 'Failed to load from plugin jar'

Tags: neo4j

I've been trying to restart neo4j after adding new data on an EC2 instance. I stopped the neo4j instance, then I called `systemctl start neo4j`, but when I call `cypher-shell` it says `Connection refused`, and connection to the browser port doesn't work anymore.

In the beginning I assumed it was a heap space problem, since looking at the `debug.log` it said there was a memory issue. I adjusted the heap space and cache settings in `neo4j.conf` as recommended by `neo4j-admin memrec`, but still neo4j won't start.

Then I assumed it was because my APOC package was outdated. My neo4j version is 3.5.6, but APOC is 3.5.0.3. I download the latest 3.5.0.4 version, but still neo4j won't start.

At last I tried `chmod 777` on every file in the `data/database` and `plugin` directories and the directories themselves, but still neo4j won't start.

What's strange is when I try `neo4j console` for all of these attempts, both `cypher-shell` and the neo4j browser port works just fine. However, obviously I would prefer to be able to launch neo4j with `systemctl`.

Right now the only hint of error I can find in `debug.log` is the following:

```
2019-06-19 21:19:55.508+0000 INFO [o.n.i.d.DiagnosticsManager] Storage summary:
2019-06-19 21:19:55.508+0000 INFO [o.n.i.d.DiagnosticsManager]   Total size of store: 3.07 GB
2019-06-19 21:19:55.509+0000 INFO [o.n.i.d.DiagnosticsManager]   Total size of mapped files: 3.07 GB
2019-06-19 21:19:55.509+0000 INFO [o.n.i.d.DiagnosticsManager] --- STARTED diagnostics for KernelDiagnostics:StoreFiles
END ---
2019-06-19 21:19:55.509+0000 INFO [o.n.k.a.DatabaseAvailabilityGuard] Fulfilling of requirement 'Database available' mak
es database available.
2019-06-19 21:19:55.509+0000 INFO [o.n.k.a.DatabaseAvailabilityGuard] Database is ready.
2019-06-19 21:19:55.568+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DatabaseHealth] Database health set to OK
2019-06-19 21:19:56.198+0000 WARN [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] Failed to load `apoc.util.s3.S3URLConnection` from plugin jar `
/var/lib/neo4j/plugins/apoc-3.5.0.4-all.jar`: com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration
2019-06-19 21:19:56.199+0000 WARN [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] Failed to load `apoc.util.s3.S3Aws` from plugin jar `/var/lib/n
eo4j/plugins/apoc-3.5.0.4-all.jar`: com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentials
2019-06-19 21:19:56.200+0000 WARN [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] Failed to load `apoc.util.s3.S3Aws$1` from plugin jar `/var/lib
/neo4j/plugins/apoc-3.5.0.4-all.jar`: com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3ObjectInputStream
2019-06-19 21:19:56.207+0000 WARN [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] Failed to load `apoc.util.hdfs.HDFSUtils$1` from plugin jar `/v
ar/lib/neo4j/plugins/apoc-3.5.0.4-all.jar`: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream
2019-06-19 21:19:56.208+0000 WARN [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] Failed to load `apoc.util.hdfs.HDFSUtils` from plugin jar `/var
/lib/neo4j/plugins/apoc-3.5.0.4-all.jar`: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataOutputStream
...
...
...
2019-06-19 21:20:00.678+0000 INFO [o.n.g.f.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory] Shutting down database.
2019-06-19 21:20:00.679+0000 INFO [o.n.g.f.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory] Shutdown started
2019-06-19 21:20:00.679+0000 INFO [o.n.k.a.DatabaseAvailabilityGuard] Database is unavailable.
2019-06-19 21:20:00.684+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Checkpoint triggered by "Database shutdown" @ txId: 1
 checkpoint started...
2019-06-19 21:20:00.704+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Checkpoint triggered by "Database shutdown" @ txId: 1
 checkpoint completed in 20ms
2019-06-19 21:20:00.705+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.p.LogPruningImpl] No log version pruned, last checkpoint was made in vers
ion 0
2019-06-19 21:20:00.725+0000 INFO [o.n.i.d.DiagnosticsManager] --- STOPPING diagnostics START ---
2019-06-19 21:20:00.725+0000 INFO [o.n.i.d.DiagnosticsManager] --- STOPPING diagnostics END ---
2019-06-19 21:20:00.725+0000 INFO [o.n.g.f.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory] Shutdown started
2019-06-19 21:20:05.875+0000 INFO [o.n.g.f.m.e.CommunityEditionModule] No locking implementation specified, defaulting
to 'community'
2019-06-19 21:20:06.080+0000 INFO [o.n.g.f.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory] Creating database.
2019-06-19 21:20:06.154+0000 INFO [o.n.k.a.DatabaseAvailabilityGuard] Requirement `Database available` makes database unavailable.
2019-06-19 21:20:06.156+0000 INFO [o.n.k.a.DatabaseAvailabilityGuard] Database is unavailable.
2019-06-19 21:20:06.183+0000 INFO [o.n.i.d.DiagnosticsManager] --- INITIALIZED diagnostics START ---
```

I think the warning isn't an issue, since it's just a warning and not an error or exception. Also it seems that the database just shuts down automatically, and then restarts, creating an infinite loop. This loop does not happen when I call `neo4j console` (all the warnings still exist in the logs). All my ports are default.

Any clue why this is happening? I've never encountered this error when I previously launched neo4j on this instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works with `neo4j console` but not with `systemctl`, you should check the rights of the Neo4j folder.

I'm pretty sure you have a problem on it, and that the `systemctl` doesn't run Neo4j with the same user as you

Comment: Yeah, it seems that adding new data changed some ownerships. I did a `chown` and now it works. [Additional information can be found here](https://community.neo4j.com/t/service-neo4j-start-gets-stuck-in-a-restart-loop/5611)